# Angular Header/Http/RequestOptions deprecated since angular 6.0, how to update them to angular 8.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have this block how it usually goes when doing httprequests in angular 6.0

[image]

I tried using the newer ones provided by angular 8.0 being HttpClient, HttpResponse, and HttpHeaders. But none of the syntax matched. How would I add the newer syntax in 8.0 to this?

Answer (score 8):

You should import from `@angular/common/http` like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

`HTTP` is `HTTPClient`
`Headers` is `HttpHeaders`

and No RequestOptions;

Example:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 });
 let options = {
    headers: headers
 }

this.http.post(URL, param, options)....
```

Refer official docs - https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Make sure to import HttpClientModule in your parent module [https://angular.io/guide/http#setup]

Example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: thank you, did the changes as suggested but response is not being found
https://imgur.com/nUnN8Sg

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `HttpClientModule` is imported in `app.module.ts`.
Having imported `HttpClientModule` into the `AppModule`, you can inject the `HttpClient` into your Application/service class.

You  need to import `HttpClient` from `'@angular/common/http';` in your service.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Inject `HttpClient` in place of `Http` in your service and use the instance for making HTTP requests.

```
post(url: string, value: any) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('X-UDS-USER', sessionStorage.getItem('username'))
  .append('token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));

  return this.http.post(url, value, {headers: headers}).map(response: HttpResponse) => {
    // do something  with response here
  }
}
```

Comment: hi there, I did the following updates to my code but response is not being found
https://imgur.com/nUnN8Sg